# Django - Generic detail_view doesn't accept an object_list

Tags: python, django, listview, detailsview, django-generic-views

I have the following in urls.py:

```
url(r'frameworkslist/(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(queryset=Category.objects.all().order_by("id"), template_name='home/subcategory.html'))
```

And in my html template:

```
{% extends "Layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

  {{ subcategory.Name }}
  {% for item in object_list %}
      <h5> <a href="/search/{{ item.id }}">{{ item.Name }}</a> </h5>
  {% endfor %}
  <a href = "/frameworkslist/">Back to framework list</a>
{% endblock %}
```

I was wondering why object_list was empty but when I changed my urls to the following, it worked. (returned the **ListView** template **instead** of **DetailView**):

```
url(r'frameworkslist/(?P<pk>\d+)$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Subcategory.objects.all().order_by("id"), template_name='home/subcategory.html'))
```

Also to note, it seems like passing the variable "model=Subcategory" to the DetailView would return the first record (or what should be a single model) of the Subcategory table and pass that to the Template. So my question is two-part, the second being: **How do you a collection of objects to DetailView Template?**

Answer (score 1):

`DetailView` is used for viewing a single object, and `ListView` is for, well, a list of objects. Usually the pattern is you have a `ListView` which has links to many individual things (like products), and then each product is viewed through a `DetailView`.

`ListView` is the one that automatically populates the `object_list` variable with your queryset.

In case of `DetailView`, it takes the queryset you provide and then uses the variables in the url to `get()` a single one. In your example that would be `Subcategory.objects.all().order_by("id").get(pk={some number})`. This is then given to the template in the `object` variable by default.

[Lots more info on class based views here](http://ccbv.co.uk/).

---

As a side note, you should be using the [`{% url %}` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url) in your templates rather than hard coding the urls.